# WPF - issues with StackPanel

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and i can not figure some things out. I just started an new project and i wanted to make a StackPanel because i saw that on a tutorial. But now i've implemented the StackPanel and i get 2 errors.

> The object 'Window' already has a child and cannot add 'StackPanel'. 'Window' can accept only one child. Line 9 Position 116.
>
> The property 'Content' is set more than once.

Can someone explain to me what i am doeing wrong.
This is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckDatabase.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CheckDatabase" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Margin="10,80,10,10" >
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ButtonPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Margin="0,10,0,10">Button 1</Button>
    <Button Margin="0,10,0,10">Button 2</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the window can only have one panel as a child just delete the grid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Window` can only contain one child. However, your `Window` contains both a `Grid` and a `StackPanel`.

To fix this you need to put the `StackPanel` inside the grid (if that is the intention) or wrap both the `Grid` and the `StackPanel` inside another panel that positions the two elements in the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Some Controls like `Window` can only have a single child. You will have to remove the `Grid` or either nest another `Grid` arround your `Grid` and `Stackpanel`.

Example:

```
 <Grid x:Name="outerGrid">
     <Grid x:Name="innerGrid"></Grid>
     <StackPanel x:Name="innerStackPanel></StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Window` is a `ContentControl` and hence can have only one `Content`. You can do the following to have the expected layout

```
<Window x:Class="CheckDatabase.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CheckDatabase" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
  <Grid Margin="10,80,10,10" >
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
  </Grid>

  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ButtonPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Margin="0,10,0,10">Button 1</Button>
    <Button Margin="0,10,0,10">Button 2</Button>
  </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```